# Where can I watch or buy Captain Tsubasa J in English?

Tags: captain-tsubasa

Where can I find *Captain Tsubasa J* first 33 episodes in English subbed? Every website I try only has first 3 episodes then then last 4. I was wondering is there a website you know of I can buy or watch it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AnimeNewsNetwork page](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1782) of the series it hasn't been licensed in English so there aren't any official English subtiltes available either.